# Where can I have lenticular images created?

Tags: printing, service-recommendation, lenticular-printing

It might be me using the wrong term for what I have in mind, but I cannot find how and where I can have lenticular images developed.

I mean those things that display two (or more) different images depending on the angle you look at it. Often, they are also holographic/3D.

A quick Google search only revealed large printers that won't do anything below a certain quantity. And I'm in Canada, so providers which can provide service here would be most relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do lenticular photography work for several of my clients on a regular basis. The phrase I believe you're looking for (at least here in the States) is 'Lenticular Printing.' When I did a Google search on the phrase 'no minimum lenticular printing' there were several outfits that claimed to be able to do short-runs with no-minimums... Is the problem that you've found these firms already but they won't work with you because you're in Canada? Or is it more getting the phrase 'lenticular printing' right so Google is able to return you good search results?

Comment: The problem was my frasing. I eventually figured out the "lenticular printing" myself, but I didn't figure out the "no minimum". If you're not a native speaker, you don't get to the "right" expression that easily :)