# What is Stereoscopic Photography?

Tags: 3d

The title says it all, what really is Stereoscopic photography?  How can I achieved it? Feel free to post a Stereoscopic photograph for better understanding.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9100/how-do-i-go-about-creating-3d-photographs/9103#9103

Comment: +1 Did not know there was something like this for photography too.

Comment: Thanks for marking it as "Duplicate" I didn't mean to duplicate any question, it was around a couple of days ago when I encountered that word.

Answer (score 5):

Stereoscopic photography is the art of taking two photos of the same thing from a vantage point approximately 9-10cm apart from each other so as to mimic the distance between the human eyes.  They are then viewed in such a way as to combine the two images.

Much more than I can write here can be gleaned from the [wikipedia entry here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy) though I'm not sure if posting a link like that breaks the rules here!

As to how to achieve this yourself, you're either going to need to buy a stereoscopic camera, though you could try it with a couple of regular cameras but there has been [much debate](http://dcinema.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/3d-stereoscopy-canon-5d-mkii-and-some-diy-tips-and-tricks/) about whether or not this actually works...