# What's it called when two photographs are printed on triangles so you see a different one from different angles?

Tags: technique, terminology, printing, lenticular-printing

This is kinda hard to explain, but I've seen it several places before. I'm looking for a special way that two photographs are printed — they're printed so you from each angle can see just one of the two photos. It's printed on a load on triangles so if you're looking from 90 degrees you wouldn't really see anything, but from approximately 60 degrees and 120 degrees, you can see the two photos.

```
                 _________
                   /   \ 
   see photo two           see photo one
```

I'm looking for the name of this printing style. I hope it's explained so you can understand it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is known as [lenticular printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_printing).

From Wikipedia: **How It Works**

> Each image is arranged (slicing) into
>   strips, which are then interlaced with
>   one or more similarly arranged images
>   (splicing). These are printed on the
>   back of a piece of plastic, with a
>   series of thin lenses molded into the
>   opposite side. Alternatively, the
>   images can be printed on paper, which
>   is then bonded to the plastic. With
>   the new technology, lenses are printed
>   in the same printing operation as the
>   interlaced image, either on both sides
>   of a flat sheet of transparent
>   material, or on the same side of a
>   sheet of paper, the image being
>   covered with a transparent sheet of
>   plastic or with a layer of
>   transparent, which in turn is printed
>   with several layers of varnish to
>   create the lenses.

A close up of the surface of a lenticular printed 3D image.

[image]

To see how movement changes the image you see, this diagram shows it pretty effectively.

[image]

Comment: +1. See also [Where can I have lenticular images created?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6392/where-can-i-have-lenticular-images-created)